# Hard Blocked In Kali Linux

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, kali-linux, network-interface

When I boot up kali linux from virtual box I get no problems. Then when I type: `ifconfig` in the terminal sometimes my wifi adapter shows up right away and sometimes it doesn't but if it doesn't then I do this, `ifconfig wlan0 down`, `ifconfig wlan0 up`, then it shows `wlan0` right away if it wasn't there already. However that's not my problem.

The problem I'm facing is it loves to hard block me whenever, like when I install new softwares/scripts on kali linux, `apt-get install`, or I try to do some attack on kali linux and then out of no where it will just hard block me for some reason.

Example would be: when I'm scanning for networks airodump-ng wlan0

```
read failed: Network is down
ioctl(SIOCSIFFLAGS) failed: Operation not possible due to RF-kill
Can't reopen wlan0
```

Then I checked if I was hard blocked

`rfkill list all`

```
0: phy0:Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

Another example of me getting hard blocked was when I did this:

`ifconfig wlan0 down`

`ifconfig wlan0 up`

```
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Input/output error
```

Then I checked to see if I was hard blocked

`rfkill list all`

```
1: phy1:Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

Like I said before these aren't the only examples I'm showing of me getting hard blocked.

The model of my labtop is `MacBook Pro11,1`

`Hyper-Threading Enabled`

I also have the `wifi connected on my mac os` but not on `kali linux` because I choose `NAT NETWORK` in the `Network section of Virtual Box`.

The wifi adapter I'm using is `Linksys AE3000`

The type of kali linux I installed was from `https://zsecurity.org/download-custom-kali`

And everything is up to date cause I did `apt-get update` and I got

```
Err:1 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-last-snapshot InRelease 
  Could not resolve 'http.kali.org'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-last-snapshot/InRelease Could not resolve 'http.kali.org'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Could someone pls help.

Comment: What is the first paragraph for? Edit question to tell us what you mean by hard-block.

Comment: This is very confusing. You say "I also have the wifi connected on my mac os **but not on kali linux**", yet you talk about wlan0 on Kali. Doesn't Kali have a wired interface connected to the VirtualBox NAT network? How do you map the Mac's WiFi interface to the VM?

Comment: By the way, there is an old discussion in the Kali forum that addresses this: https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?18311-WiFi-hardware-blocked-RFkill-not-working. This version of Kali doesn't run in a VM, though.